# why is Git pull throws an error: cannot be used without a working tree

Tags: windows, backup, git

I have installed Git version 1.7.6.msysgit.0 on our Windows 2003 Server (SP2). This is our main repository for 14 developers.

I am trying to create a backup from this repository. The way I am trying is:
I made a clone of this repo on our backup server:

```
cd to/my/backup/git/folder.git
git clone z:/GIT/Lib.git .
```

I am now trying to pull changes from the main repository, but I get the following error

```
git pull
Fatal: ... git-clone cannot be used without a working tree
```

The config file under Z:/GIT/Lib.git is:

```
Z:\GIT\Lib.git>more config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
        url = //NAS/GIT/Lib
```

Running

```
git status
```

throws the same error.

I thought the problem was with the :

```
bare=true
```

so I changed it, but did not change the result.

I will NEVER work on the backup folders ( I have 4 repos now under z:/GIT/  - and all need to be backed up in the same way - or somehow)

This [article](http://grahamc.com/blog/multiple-git-repositories-one-directory-dotfiles/) mentions that I need this work-tree, but if I set it, can I have the other repos pulled as well?

The question can be asked also in another format as: What is the best way to make a GIT backup ?

Comment: Which windows-git are you running? There are a couple of packages out there.

Comment: I missed that: git version 1.7.6.msysgit.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `bare` at this point won't automagically fix your issue, it's already a bare repository (a repo without a working tree).  Use `git fetch` instead of `git pull` and you should be fine (`git pull` is basically just a `git fetch` to pull in all the updates followed by a `git merge` to merge the updates into your working tree).

Comment: super, thanks.  All I do than to backup is: git fetch   *I am not merging anything, as it's only a backup folder.